# How can I call one asynchronous function in a group way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, typescript, async-await

I am sorry that I may not be able to describe this issue clearly. I will try:

Now I have one asynchronous function which takes data and do something, e.g.

```
function myFunction(num: number):Promise<void> {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
     console.log(num);
     return;
   });
}
```

I want to print 5 numbers in a group (the order doesn't matter). What matters is that I want to print the next 5 numbers after the previous group finishes.
For example:

```
1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 10 ... is valid
7, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 ... is not valid
```

How can I make this happen if I have to use this function? I have to maker sure the first five calls of this function have been resolved and then spin up calls of the next five functions. I know this seems weird, I'm trying to abstract my current problem into this number problem.

Thank you for any comments or idea.

Comment: Is this typescript? If so you should add the tag

Comment: make sure you only make 5 calls to myFunction at a time - then wait on each set of 5 with Promise.all - but, as this is typescript, there may be a completely different way

Comment: Well it might not be Typescript, most likely is like.. But It could be Flow :)

Comment: Your `myFunction` is never calling `resolve`?!

Comment: Yes. I am writing in typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by breaking an array into chunks and processing the chunks using `Array#map` and `Promise#all`. You can then string the chunk processing together using `Array#reduce`:

```
runChunkSeries([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5, someAsyncFn);

// our placeholder asynchronous function
function someAsyncFn(value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 5000);
  }).then(() => console.log(value));
}

function runChunkSeries(arr, chunkSize, fn) {
  return runSeries(chunk(arr, chunkSize), (chunk) => Promise.all(chunk.map(fn)));
}

// Run fn on each element of arr asynchronously but in series
function runSeries(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce((promise, value) => {
    return promise.then(() => fn(value));
  }, Promise.resolve());
}

// Creates an array of elements split into groups the length of chunkSize
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  const chunks = [];
  const {length} = arr;
  const chunkCount = Math.ceil(length / chunkSize);

  for(let i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i * chunkSize, (i + 1) * chunkSize));
  }

  return chunks;
}
```

Here's a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/ALbZJv?editors=0010).

Answer (score 1):

I would use generators, or since you are using typescript, you could use es7 async/await syntax, and using lodash you could do something like this:

```
(async function(){
  const iterations: number = 2;
  const batchSize: number = 5;
  let tracker: number = 0;
  _.times(iterations, async function(){
     // We execute the fn 5 times and create an array with all the promises
     tasks: Promise[] = _.times(batchSize).map((n)=> myFunction(n + 1 + tracker))
     await tasks // Then we wait for all those promises to resolve
     tracker += batchSize;
  })
})()
```

You can replace lodash with for/while loops if you wish.

Check 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/03/what-about-asyncawait/

If i didn't understand correctly or there is something wrong with the code, let me know and i'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Zagen for the reply! I am wondering if there is a way without using `async` or `await` for this. In my current development, the rule doesn't allow us to use these. I can use Promise.all() but I don't really know how to write this code.

Comment: @Lubor, yes of course you can do it without async/await (weird thing to forbid), you can choose promises or even regular callbacks but the code won't be as simple. Check SimpleJ answer, its a nice implementation and it only uses promises.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple using `async`/`await` actually:

```
(async function() {
    var i = 0;
    while (true) {
        for (var promises = []; promises.length < 5; ) {
            promises.push(myFunction(i++));
        }
        await Promise.all(promises);
    }
}());
```