# AJAX requests pool

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have array of [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) objects and I want to post them to same URL. I want to make fixed number of AJAX requests at a time, for that I want to create pool of xhr objects. How to do that?

Comment: What do you specifically mean by a "pool"?

Comment: If you wrap your AJAX requests in promises, you could use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863062/how-can-i-call-one-asynchronous-function-in-a-group-way/39863245#39863245) to solve this problem.

Comment: By pool I mean array of XMLHttpRequest objects.

Comment: @simpleJ can you give code snippet

Comment: I think he only wants (n) ajax requests current at any time.  If so, use a loop to fire off the initial ajax requests, then have the success or fail handler call a function to start the next request if any remain to be sent.

Comment: @user41451 Sure. [Here](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/MJqdbK?editors=1010) is a codepen. It doesn't actually run because I don't have any data and I didn't implement the XHR request stuff, but it should be fairly clear how you could use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.splice()`, `Promise.all()`, `fetch()` to perform `N` requests at a time.

```
let data = [FormData, FormData, ..];

let N = 5;

let pool = data.splice(0, N);

let processData = requests => 
  Promise.all(
    requests.map(fd =>
      fetch("/path/to/server", {
        method: "POST",
        body: fd
      })
      .then(response => response.ok)
    )
  )
  .then(responses => responses.every(result => result))
  .then(result => {
    if (result) {
      if (data.length) {
        pool = data.splice(0, N);
        return true
      }
    }
    return "complete"
  });    

let fn = next => next === true ? processData(pool).then(fn) : next;

processData(pool)
.then(fn)
.then(complete => console.log(complete))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ce1kzu52/5/

You can also process the array without scheduling the function `processData` to be called again if any elements are remaining in array.